# Change Windows RDP connection bar position

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, rdp, personalization

I frequently browse internet while using RDP, and the position of connection bar at the top of the window is annoying while switching between tabs. How is it possible to change the position of Windows RDP connection bar to the any other side of the window? Not unpinning the bar, shrinking or sliding along the top end of the window, but shift to any other end either left/right/bottom, or totally get rid of it altogether.

OS: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the bar entirely by deselecting the "Display the connection bar when I use the full screen" box in the Remote Desktop Connection window.

To exit full-screen, you can use Ctrl+Alt+Break, you can also exit by selecting the power menu and using "disconnect".

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Z9Y244p.png]

Comment: for anyone who might think this doesn't work, even when disabled, the bar will be visible for few seconds after you connect, just give it time to disappear and you're done

Comment: @flagg19 Thank you. These types of comments might seem trivial but are genuinely helpful at times. Note to self: Don't hesitate writing such comments.

Comment: Is there a way to make this change permanent for all future sessions?