# Hide RDP connection bar for all future sessions

Tags: windows, rdp

I use one-time-use RDP sessions extensively for work. The position of the bar at the top of the screen frequently gets in the way.

The solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576779/change-windows-rdp-connection-bar-position) works to hide it, IF you have access to the GUI. I can't open the GUI on each session when I launch (I get an RDP file I have to run). I discovered that if I edit the session file very quickly, add `displayconnectionbar:i:0`, save, and execute, that works. It is however very cumbersome.

How can I make it so all future sessions default to `displayconnectionbar:i:0`? I've already checked the setting in the hidden file `Documents/Default.rdp` but that doesn't seem to apply to these downloaded sessions. Maybe a registry entry somewhere?